# jQuery not columnizing in chrome, until refresh

Tags: jquery, wordpress, multiple-columns

I seem to only get this in chrome, but the columnizing jQuery at http://www.womensselfdefense.info/ will often fail, until you click refresh.

Sometimes you have to click around the site until you get it to finally fail. Spotty.

I have tried many alternatives to jQuery(document).ready(function() { which are supposed to fix jQuery/refresh bug, but no avail.

**History:**

*This was working perfectly till the last Wordpress update, which broke the columnizer script completely, causing page to hang while loading.*

*Then I applied this fix so no more page hang https://github.com/adamwulf/Columnizer-jQuery-Plugin/pull/115*

*But since then, while browsing around the site sometimes pages will fail to columnize until "refresh" ?!?!*

*I tested with all wordpress plugins disabled which makes it happen less frequently, but still happens*

*I was able to duplicate this on a fresh wordpress install as well. (www.womensselfdefense.info/dev/) where there ar eno plugins. less frequent but still occasionally happens, as above.*

Answer (score 0):

I refreshed 10 times and I didn't notice any error with you web page. Everything seems to be fine. Anyway, why are you using jquery columns? I suggest you to use CSS3 Columns ( http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_multiple_columns.asp ).

Comment: "refreshing" makes it work correctly. clicking around the site in chrome (via menu) makes it fail.

Currently not using css3 columns because the many versions of IE which don't support it.